# Python nested function scope

Tags: python

I have a python hash that contains a mapping of function name to function. I want to modify each hash entry to call the associated function BUT then to also call a final custom function. It's to act somewhat like an exit hook.

```
def original():
    print "original work"
```

becomes

```
def replacement():
    original()
    print "notify somebody..."
```

My issue is I think I'm getting my scoping etc., wrong as the output of the following code is not as expected. Maybe if I could ask is there a better way to do this? I want to stick with modifying the original cb has as it third party code and less places I change the better.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

def a():
    print "a"

def b():
    print "b"

def c():
    print "c"


orig_fxn_cb = dict()

" basic name to function callback hash "
orig_fxn_cb['a'] = a
orig_fxn_cb['b'] = b
orig_fxn_cb['c'] = c

" for each call back routine in the hash append a final action to it "
def appendFxn(fxn_cb):
    appended_fxn_cb_new = dict()
    for i in orig_fxn_cb.keys():
        cb = fxn_cb[i]
        def fxn_tail():
            cb()
            print cb.__name__, "tail" 

        appended_fxn_cb_new[i] = fxn_tail
        appended_fxn_cb_new[i]()
    return appended_fxn_cb_new

" make up a modified callback hash "
xxx = appendFxn(orig_fxn_cb)
print xxx

for i in xxx:
    print xxx[i]()
```

Comment: If I may, your variable names aren't the most descriptive. That definitely makes it harder to keep track of what's going on.

Comment: how about using a decorator?

Comment: @jterrace I'd post that as an answer.

Comment: What's the `appended_fxn_cb_new[i]()` line for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you after:

```
from functools import wraps

def notifier(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print "notify somebody..."
        return res
    return wrapped

@notifier
def original():
    print "original work"

# or: original = notifier(original)

original()
```

```
original work
notify somebody...
```

Comment: Decorators to the rescue! BTW, you don't have to use `functools.wraps`, but it makes sure to preserve the docstring and argument signature of the wrapped (decorated) function, so it's a good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: @jathanism: _"it makes sure to preserve the argument signature"_ - pretty sure that's not the case, and you have to get the `decorator` module for that. (Which works by generating python code as a string).

Comment: It's worth noting that you can also call decorators explicitly. For example, when creating your `dict` from names to functions, you can do, e.g., `d['foo'] = notifier(foo)`.

Comment: @jathanism: Yes, Eric is right. Try it out: `def foo(): pass`, then `bar=notifier(foo)`, then `help(foo)` shows `foo()`, while `help(bar)` shows `bar(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. So just the docstring. Got it! :)

Comment: I'll use this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into has to do with the `cb` variable that you're using in your `appendFxn` function. Your inner function definitions access this value by name, and so they all end up having a reference to the same inner callback function (whichever one came up last in the iteration).

You can fix this with a default argument in your wrapper function:

```
def appendFxn(fxn_cb):
    appended_fxn_cb_new = dict()
    for i in orig_fxn_cb.keys():
        cb = fxn_cb[i]
        def fxn_tail(cb = cb):           # fix is here!
            cb()
            print cb.__name__, "tail" 

        appended_fxn_cb_new[i] = fxn_tail
        appended_fxn_cb_new[i]()
    return appended_fxn_cb_new
```

Using a default argument binds the *current value* of `cb` to the `cb` name within the inner function. That way, even when the original `cb` variable gets set to a new value, the existing function will keep the old one. (You could also make the function argument `cb = fxn_cb[i]` and get rid of the outer `cb` variable if you want.)

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the expected output, it seems to work fine here. It replaces all functions in the dictionary with a copy that calls the original and then prints the original name and "tail". As it replaces the functions, it also executes them. In the end, you iterate over the resulting dictionary and execute them again.

Something that may give you unexpected behavior if you call appendFxn many times is the `for i in orig_fxn_cb.keys():` line. It references the global `orig_fxn_cb` instead of the `fxn_cb` parameter passed, so further calls will not change the functions in the map.